# mysql: can a call to a stored procedure be placed in a json_object function?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I can use a stored function within a json_object function:

```
json_object(
                          'id', concat(b.category, '-',b.subcategory),
                          'name',b.subcategory,
                          'data', json_object( 
                                        'trait', b.subcategory,
                                        'risk', *assess(rs, ID)*,
...
```

But when I try to use a stored procedure it causes an error:

```
json_object(
                          'id', concat(b.category, '-',b.subcategory),
                          'name',b.subcategory,
                          'data', json_object( 
                                        'trait', b.subcategory,
                                        'risk', *call assess(rs, ID)*,
...
```

Is there a proper way to use a stored procedure in place of a stored function?

Comment: Can't you just run it before this query?

Comment: no, because its building a nested json and needs to be called at that level

Comment: Then you'll probably need to wrap it in a function (assuming the undisclosed error is a syntax error). But I can't really understand why location matters, since it isn't returning anything anyway.